# Support for NeuronDotNet3.0

Tags: neural-network, biological-neural-network

I wondered if any of you know, if there is support for [NeuronDotNet 3.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/). The website neurondotnet.freehostia.com is down, and I am looking for more example Files or instructions how to properly use the library.

Do you guys have any ideas? I would be greatly appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

I recall there being a message on the site stating that the project had been discontinued.  If you are looking for a .Net neural network API you might condier.

- **Encog** http://www.encog.org
- **AForge** https://code.google.com/p/aforge/

Disclaimer: I am one of the lead developers for Encog.